# Ruby on rails foreach with bootstrap3 row class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I would like to foreach loop through data and display this data usings bootstraps grid system having 3 columns per row, however i will need multiple rows for the amount of data as below:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
<div class="col-md-4">*DATA HERE*</div>
</div>
```

Can someone advise how to achieve this using a foreach in rails, obviously the below would only render 1 .row class and place all col-md-4 items returned into it. I would like it to create another .row class after it reaches 3 items per row and start again. I hope that makes sense! What i have so far:

```
<div class="row">
<% @work.each do |w| %>
<div class="col-md-6">
<%= w.image_url %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
<% @work.each_slice(3) do |works| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% works.each do |work| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">*work.name*</div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```